# angular 2 how to check if control is visible or not

Tags: validation, angular

I am building a for and has ngControl on different form. I want to check if the ngControl is visible then only fire the validation otherwise not.

How can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 1):

If you use the model-driven approach to building a form, you control when/how the validation is executed.
There is a video on how to do this here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ihYc9y7dQA0